Constructing a polynomial with given intersection multiplicity with another polynomial at a point using linear algebra.
Assume that I am given a fixed polynomial $f(x,y)$ of degree $D$ in two variables, and assume that $(0,0) \in V(f) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ is a non-singular point on $V(f)$. I would like to construct a polynomial (or rather the vector space of all such polynomials) $g(x,y)$ of degree $d$ that meets $f$ in $(0,0)$ with (at least) a given multiplicity $n$. This construction should ideally be expressed via solving a linear system with indeterminates being the coefficients of $g$.
The concrete example that I am currently working on is given by $f = x^6 + (y+i)^6 + 1, d = 4$ and $n=2$.

Here are my thoughts so far:
We write
\begin{equation}
f = f_0 + f_1 + f_2 + \dots + f_D, \qquad g = g_0 + g_1 + g_2 + \dots + g_d
\end{equation}
with each $f_i$ resp. $g_j$ homogeneous of degree $i$ resp $j$.
If $n=1$ then it suffices and is necessary to postulate that $f_0 = 0 = g_0$.
If $n=2$, then I can postulate that both $f$ and $g$ disappear and the "linearlizations" of $f$ and $g$ agree, i.e. $f_0 = 0 = g_0$ and $f_1 = \lambda g_1$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.
My goal is to go to generalize to $n\geq3$. My intuition would say that if the cut-offs of $f$ and $g$ after their degree $n-1$ part agree up to scaling, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f_0 + f_1 + \dots + f_{n-1} = \lambda (g_0 + g_1 + \dots + g_{n-1})
\end{equation}
then this should suffice. But it is certainly not necessary as for example $f(x,y) = y - x^3$ and $g(x,y) = y$ meet with multiplicity 3 in the origin.

I have seen that the intersection multiplicity may be expressed via the resultant of $f$ and $g$, though it appears to me that in that case we lose linear dependence on the coefficients of $g$.
Is there still a way to proceed?
Best,
Clemens

Thank you for pointing out how my example still fits the setting. That helped a lot.

I happen to have a follow-up question: Say I want to work with the curve defined by $x^4 + y^4 -1 = 0$ and I consider the tangent line given by $y-1 = 0$. This line has a tangent point of multiplicity 4 in $(0,1)$. A shift to the origin tells me that I should compute the intersection number of
$y^4 - 4y^3 + 6y^2 - 4y$ and $y$
in the origin. Does in this case the necessary and sufficient condition translate to: The "cut-off" $4y^3 - 6y^2 + 4y$ lies in the ideal $\langle y \rangle$?

Hmm, wait, sorry, I lied! That example shows me my earlier claim was wrong. I think you have to use the resultant.

In the end I was able to construct the polynomials I need by hand. I would still hope that there is a general linear method, but most likely I will not come across another curve where I can do explicit calculations. So maybe this is now irrelevant. ^^
